# Navigation Links Issue on ScrollView with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have been using a ScrollView with a Vertical scroll instead of ListView with SwiftUI because of Customisation Limitations with ListView. I have found with Views Embedded in Such Scroll View along with Navigation Link, the icons or Images in such views are highlighted. This is happening on Xcode 11 beta 3 SwiftUI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PresentationButton hides Image in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798491/presentationbutton-hides-image-in-view)

Comment: please add some code for example, also you may forget to embed in NavigationView ?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue this is my code

[image: After navigation]

If I Comment NavigationLink this will happen :

[image]

---

### SOLUTION

After searching on web I found the solution

After NavigationLink add this line :

```
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: This solution saves me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With SwiftUI with Buttons having Action handler we get a Default Blue icon. To avoid add an dafault Parameter .buttonStyle(.plain)